# Findbugs 'null pointer dereference' warning for ImmutableList but not for Arrays.asList

Tags: java, findbugs

I get 'NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE: Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method' for com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of(..) but not for java.util.Arrays.asList(..) for exact same input. [FindBugs](https://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) documentation does not mention about this difference or at least I could not locate it. Need your help understanding what is going on?

Example:

```
public class SomeClass{
  private String name;
  public SomeClass(String name){
  this.name=name;
 }
 public String getName(){
   return name;
 }
}
public class OtherClass{
  public void aMethod(SomeClass object){
   
  ImmutableList.of(object.getName()); // Find bugs NP warning
  Arrays.asList(object.getName()); // No warning

 }
}
```

Comment: It could be because `ImmutableList` doesn't allow null values, but `Arrays.asList` does.

Comment: It seems both of them do not allow null values in slightly different ways. e.g. Arrays.asList("a", null) is fine but Arrays.asList(null) will throw null pointer. However ImmutableList.of("a", null) will throw null pointer.